# simplexml parsing with php

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to print out the xml child "pizza" on a php page. Though it is not working, here is my code for parsing the xml file.

```
<? 

  $dom = simplexml_load_file("menu.xml");

  foreach ($dom->menu->categories->pizzas->pizza as $pizza)
  {
      echo $pizza;
  }


?>
```

This is the xml file

```
 <menu>
 <categories>
 <pizzas> 
       <pizza>Cheese Pizza</pizza>
   <pizza>Beef PIzza</pizza>
   <pizza>Chickens Wings Pizza</pizza>
 </pizzas>
 </categories>
 </menu>
```

I would just like to print out the different kinds of pizzas on my php page. I would like to display a menu on the page.

I get an error of  "Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/home.php on line 15"

Please Help!
Thanks

Comment: Still obligated to ask.. You have included the simplexml library right?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the top level element `menu` from that loop and use

```
foreach ($dom->categories->pizzas->pizza as $pizza)
{
    echo $pizza;
}
```

If you do  `print_r($dom);` you will get a proof of that structure.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
    $dom = simplexml_load_file("menu.xml");
    foreach($dom->categories->pizzas->pizza as $pizza) {
        echo $pizza;
    } // Try This
?>
```

Comment: How is your answer different from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23003671/1003917) that was answered 19 mins ago ? Just asking..